# Radio and Checkbox in primefaces datatable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have to put radio and chechbox controls in primefaces's 2.2.1 datatable but not as a selection mode controls. I want to bind that controls as a values for the backing bean.

For example:

A have a list of some configurations and in that list only one configuration can be active at one time (radiobox) but every single configuration can be active or not (selectbox).

Datatable doesn't have to be editable, because I will change values in another window. Only controls should be in the datatable.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is definitely possible I do this all the time in my datatables. However, you need to keep in mind that each row will require identification. You can do this with objects or parameters to your listener:

```
//Backing Bean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean
{
  private ArrayList<Element> elements;
  TestBean(){...}

  public ArrayList<Element> getElements(){...} //Initialize things here

  public class Element
  {
     /* getter/setter and initialization assumed */
     private boolean selected;
     private String radioSelection = "one";
     private String[] radioChoices = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
     public void selectMe(ActionEvent evt)
     {
       System.out.println("Selected -> " + this); 
     } 
  }
}
```

//HTML

```
<p:dataTable value="testBean.elements" var="element">
  <p:column>
    <p:commandButton value="Select" actionListener="#{element.selectMe}"
  </p:column>

  <p:column>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{element.selected}" />
  </p:column>         

  <p:column>
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{element.radioSelection}">
      <f:selectItems 
        value="#{element.radioChoices}" 
        var="item" 
        itemLabel="#{item}"  
        itemValue="#{item}" 
      />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

You can (and might want to) use a parameter using the ID from the element or whatever your preferred pattern is. The key is remembering that each row has its own id and you're creating a set of elements, not a single element. That's where you're most likely to get bound up. Seeing as how each button is a first class citizen you should be able to whatever you want with it.

Edit:
  I added a Radio/Checkbox example. It sounds like you're new to JSF so I'd advise reading up on the SelectItem class and run through how combo-boxes etc... work. The key to remember (as I stress above) is that you're rendering a lot of components so if you share a value it can easily lead to behavior you don't want. Encapsulate everything and you're usually in good shape.) You can also look at bindings as a possible solution. It all depends on where you'd rather write your code.

Comment: Ok, but how to ensure radio button "grouping", which means that only one radio button can be selected at the same time? And also, h:selectBooleanCheckbox and h:selectOneRadio don't have "actionListener" property.

Comment: I've updated this to reflect radio and checkboxes. You should be aware there are other listeners like valueChanged etc... available so there's more than one way to do this. Bindings are also extremely powerful if you need complex behaviors.

Comment: @Nikola http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-radio-buttons-example/ this is a pretty good walkthrough for radio-options in standard JSF

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear, but how can I ensure that each radio button should appear on each datatable row and has "grouping policy"? In your example, radio buttons "one" "two" and "three" are in the same row.

Comment: If you want things to apply to the whole table a logical place would be in the header for the column. <f:facet name="header">content</f:facet>

Comment: I tried with:   <f:facet name="header">
   <h:selectOneRadio value="#{element.radioSelection}">
        <f:selectItems 
          value="#{element.radioChoices}" 
          var="item" 
          itemLabel="#{item}"  
          itemValue="#{item}" 
        />
      </h:selectOneRadio>
  </f:facet>
but nothing is rendered. Any idea?

Comment: Yes--there's no row element for the header (think about it--its outside the row it applies to all the rows). Thus, you need to define it outside that scope. In my example, instead of in the element class, the items would be a member of TestBean. That should do the trick. You'll also need to set a valueChangeEvent or it won't update anyhting.